# calling macro from another velocity template

Tags: macros, nvelocity

I'm new and struggling with velocity templates. I have few templates in hand with lots of macros in it.

```
// file b.vm
#macro (bmacro)
 from b macro
#end

// file a.vm
#parse("//temp//b.vm")
from a
#bmacro()
```

My expectation is to get

```
from a
from b macro
```

however, I am getting only "from a" as outcome. But when I place any static text outside bmacro, it is getting along.

By the way, I'm using NVelocity from castle project.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The macro doesn't work because NVelocity (and its ancestor Velocity) determine if `#bmacro` is a directive or macro at parse time, while the `#bmacro` macro gets discovered at runtime as it jumps into the other template, and so it is passed through as text.

I answered this other question with a detailed answer a few months ago that had the same problem:
[macros not rendering in NVelocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450670/macros-not-rendering-in-nvelocity)